# AWS Regions and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda code in EU-WEST1 region. I want to use this lambda globaly. How am I supposed to do that? Should I invoke a lambda code in every region? Can I use lambda across regions?

Comment: AWS Lambda is a regional service. A single Lambda function in a single region can make API calls to AWS services in other regions, but they're remote, of course, so any data transferred between that Lambda function and the destination services or vice-versa takes longer and costs more. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you very much for your respsonse. I have lambda that is integrating Snowflake with AWS. I want to run this code across the regions. Is there anyway that I can run this code in EU-WEST-1 and it will run for diffrent regions (us-west-1). Should I run lambda seperatly in every region?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on you use case. What you exactly want to achieve.

According to this aws Lambda@Edge is designed to execute lambda on edge locations globally:
https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/

Otherwise lambda is bound to a region, so you would have to deploy it to multiple region.
see also:

1. [Building a Multi-region Serverless Application with Amazon API Gateway and AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-multi-region-serverless-application-with-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/)
2. [Deploying AWS Lambda layers automatically across multiple Regions | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/deploying-aws-lambda-layers-automatically-across-multiple-regions/)

It is possible to invoke lambda across regions, see:
[Invoke an AWS lambda across regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250426/invoke-an-aws-lambda-across-regions)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your respsonse. I have lambda that is integrating Snowflake with AWS. I want to run this code across the regions. Is there anyway that I can run this code in EU-WEST-1 and it will run for diffrent regions (us-west-1). Should I run lambda seperatly in every region?

Comment: I think yes, unless you use lambda edge which I don't have experience yet.